# Passing an object reference to an anonymous class

Tags: java, hibernate, parent-child, hibernate-criteria, anonymous-class

I'm having a few troubles with Java programming. In my case, I'm using Hibernate criteria queries through Spring's `getHibernateTemplate` without having direct access to the session object.

I have a parent-child relationship mapped with JPA annotations. Here is my DAO method

```
public List<Child> findByParent(final Parent parent)
    {
        return getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback<List<Child>>()
        {

            @Override
            public List<Child> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException
            {
                return session.createCriteria(Child.class)
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("parent", parent))
                        .list();
            }
        });
    }
```

I have marked `parent` as final because I'm passing it to the anonymous class. When I run the code Hibernate does perform the query (`... where parentId = ?`) but I get no result. Running it in mysql with correct `parentId` returns results.

When debugging, I see Eclipse can't inspect the value of `parent` from within the anonymous class. What's wrong? How do I fix this?

[edit] Here are the Pojo. I have no control over Parent (not even source, I just pressed F3 for auto decompile)

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_STORE", sequenceName = "SEQ_CHILD")
@Table(name = "TA_CHILD", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "A_FIELD", "PARENT_ID" }) })
public class Immobile
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CHILD_ID")
    protected int id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, targetEntity = Organization.class)
    protected Parent parent;

    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected String parentId;
}


// Compiled from Parent.java (version 1.6 : 50.0, super bit)
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="TA_PARENT")
public class org.Partent extends org.ExtensibleBase implements java.io.Serializable {

  // Field descriptor #161 J
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  // Field descriptor #166 Ljava/lang/String;
  @javax.persistence.Id
  @javax.persistence.Column(name="PARENT_ID",
    nullable=false,
    length=(int) 20)
  private java.lang.String id;

}
```

Comment: Can you please post you pojos Child.java and Parent.java

Comment: `parent` is not being "passed" anywhere. Rather, `parent` is *captured* by the anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

In restriction, you have to add criteria for parent entity's id
Try below code,

```
public List<Child> findByParent(final Parent parent)
        {
            return getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback<List<Child>>()
            {

                @Override
                public List<Child> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException
                {
                    return session.createCriteria(Child.class)
                            .add(Restrictions.eq("parent.id", parent.getId()))
                            .list();
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem in the code. Simply, after populating the tables from MySQL workbench I forgot to commit the transaction or leave auto commit enabled.

Both fragments (mine and Pritesh's) are correct and return all results.

Problem solved but that doesn't explain Eclipse being unable to evaluate `parent` variable, which is out of the scope